# search function with prepared statement not displaying no result

Tags: php, mysqli

When the search matches all displays perfectly. But when there is no match the no result message does not display. Please any insight on this one. Thanks upfront

```
$result = "SELECT T1.ID, T2.Image1, T1.unoone, T1.unotwo, T1.unothree,
T1.unofour
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON (T1.ID=T2.Image1) 
WHERE T1.ID=T2.Image1 AND T1.unoone LIKE '%".$uno_one."%' 
AND T1.unotwo LIKE '%".$uno_two."%' 
AND T1.unothree LIKE '%".$uno_three."%' 
AND T1.unofour LIKE '%".$uno_four."%' ";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$query = mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $result);

if(!$query) {

       die("no result");

} else {
/* execute statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* bind result variables */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $img[0], $uno_one, $uno_two, 
$uno_three, $uno_four);

/* fetch values */
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

echo $img[0];
echo $uno_one;
echo $uno_two;
echo $uno_three; 
echo $uno_four;

  }

/* close statement */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

}
```

Comment: `if(!$query) {` check if any error exists. nothing to do with result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Madan Sapkota said : "if(!$query) { only check if any error exists".

You need to use a function for counting results, like mysqli_stmt_num_rows():

```
if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows ( $stmt ) == 0 ){ echo "there is no result";}
// The while loop after won't be run when no result are found, no need to put an else here.
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
  ...    
}
```

Comment: if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows ( $stmt ) == 0 ){ echo "there is no result";}
When there is no match this works. But when there is a match then it also displays "there is no result" plus all of the rest perfectly Why is it displaying "there is no result" when there is a match.

Comment: About first comment : use `die("no result . mysqli_error($con)")`

Comment: My bad.For having `(mysqli_stmt_num_rows ( $stmt )` to work, you must use `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);` just after `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`

Comment: Then you don't have any error on your query, or you would have seen, at least, "no result". Not so related, but check again mysqli_error syntax, you made twice the same mistake in these comments (missing arg).